# change text to datetime in python

Tags: python, pandas

While converting below list to datetime am getting error as

```
OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-03-19 00:00:00
```

please suggest me how to change

```
 lst=['Dec-2015', 'Nov-2015', 'Oct-2015', 'Sep-2015', 'Aug-2015',
           'Jul-2015', 'Jun-2015', 'May-2015', 'Apr-2015', 'Mar-2015',
           'Feb-2015', 'Jan-2015', 'Mar-2018', 'Feb-2018', 'Jan-2018',
           'Sep-2017', 'Aug-2017', 'Jul-2017', 'Jun-2016', 'May-2016',
           'Apr-2016', 'Sep-2018', 'Aug-2018', 'Jul-2018', 'Jun-2017',
           'May-2017', 'Apr-2017', 'Mar-2016', 'Feb-2016', 'Jan-2016',
           'Dec-2014', 'Nov-2014', 'Oct-2014', 'Sep-2014', 'Aug-2014',
           'Jul-2014', 'Jun-2014', 'May-2014', 'Apr-2014', 'Mar-2014',
           'Feb-2014', 'Jan-2014', 'Dec-2018', 'Nov-2018', 'Oct-2018',
           'Jun-2018', 'May-2018', 'Apr-2018', 'Dec-2011', 'Nov-2011',
           'Oct-2011', 'Sep-2011', 'Aug-2011', 'Jul-2011', 'Jun-2011',
           'May-2011', 'Apr-2011', 'Mar-2011', 'Feb-2011', 'Jan-2011',
           'Dec-2010', 'Nov-2010', 'Oct-2010', 'Sep-2010', 'Aug-2010',
           'Jul-2010', 'Jun-2010', 'May-2010', 'Apr-2010', 'Mar-2010',
           'Feb-2010', 'Jan-2010', 'Dec-2009', 'Nov-2009', 'Oct-2009',
           'Sep-2009', 'Aug-2009', 'Jul-2009', 'Jun-2009', 'May-2009',
           'Apr-2009', 'Mar-2009', 'Feb-2009', 'Jan-2009', 'Dec-2008',
           'Nov-2008', 'Oct-2008', 'Sep-2008', 'Aug-2008', 'Jul-2008',
           'Jun-2008', 'May-2008', 'Apr-2008', 'Mar-2008', 'Feb-2008',
           'Jan-2008', 'Dec-2007', 'Nov-2007', 'Oct-2007', 'Sep-2007',
           'Aug-2007', 'Jul-2007', 'Jun-2007', 'Mar-2017', 'Feb-2017',
           'Jan-2017', 'Dec-2013', 'Nov-2013', 'Oct-2013', 'Sep-2013',
           'Aug-2013', 'Jul-2013', 'Jun-2013', 'May-2013', 'Apr-2013',
           'Mar-2013', 'Feb-2013', 'Jan-2013', 'Dec-2012', 'Nov-2012',
           'Oct-2012', 'Sep-2012', 'Aug-2012', 'Jul-2012', 'Jun-2012',
           'May-2012', 'Apr-2012', 'Mar-2012', 'Feb-2012', 'Jan-2012',
           'Sep-2016', 'Aug-2016', 'Jul-2016', 'Dec-2017', 'Nov-2017',
           'Oct-2017', 'Dec-2016', 'Nov-2016', 'Oct-2016', 'Mar-19', 'Feb-19',
           'Jan-19', 'Jun-19', 'May-19', 'Apr-19', 'Sep-19', 'Aug-19',
           'Jul-19']
df=pd.Series(lst)
df=pd.to_datetime(df)
```

Comment: I think this would help you [link](https://www.journaldev.com/23365/python-string-to-datetime-strptime)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that "-19" refers to "-2019," add the missing characters:

```
pd.to_datetime(df.str.replace('-19$', '-2019'))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import pandas as pd
lst=['Dec-2015', 'Nov-2015', 'Oct-2015', 'Sep-2015', 'Aug-2015',
           'Jul-2015', 'Jun-2015', 'May-2015', 'Apr-2015', 'Mar-2015',
           'Feb-2015', 'Jan-2015', 'Mar-2018', 'Feb-2018', 'Jan-2018',
           'Sep-2017', 'Aug-2017', 'Jul-2017', 'Jun-2016', 'May-2016',
           'Apr-2016', 'Sep-2018', 'Aug-2018', 'Jul-2018', 'Jun-2017',
           'May-2017', 'Apr-2017', 'Mar-2016', 'Feb-2016', 'Jan-2016',
           'Dec-2014', 'Nov-2014', 'Oct-2014', 'Sep-2014', 'Aug-2014',
           'Jul-2014', 'Jun-2014', 'May-2014', 'Apr-2014', 'Mar-2014',
           'Feb-2014', 'Jan-2014', 'Dec-2018', 'Nov-2018', 'Oct-2018',
           'Jun-2018', 'May-2018', 'Apr-2018', 'Dec-2011', 'Nov-2011',
           'Oct-2011', 'Sep-2011', 'Aug-2011', 'Jul-2011', 'Jun-2011',
           'May-2011', 'Apr-2011', 'Mar-2011', 'Feb-2011', 'Jan-2011',
           'Dec-2010', 'Nov-2010', 'Oct-2010', 'Sep-2010', 'Aug-2010',
           'Jul-2010', 'Jun-2010', 'May-2010', 'Apr-2010', 'Mar-2010',
           'Feb-2010', 'Jan-2010', 'Dec-2009', 'Nov-2009', 'Oct-2009',
           'Sep-2009', 'Aug-2009', 'Jul-2009', 'Jun-2009', 'May-2009',
           'Apr-2009', 'Mar-2009', 'Feb-2009', 'Jan-2009', 'Dec-2008',
           'Nov-2008', 'Oct-2008', 'Sep-2008', 'Aug-2008', 'Jul-2008',
           'Jun-2008', 'May-2008', 'Apr-2008', 'Mar-2008', 'Feb-2008',
           'Jan-2008', 'Dec-2007', 'Nov-2007', 'Oct-2007', 'Sep-2007',
           'Aug-2007', 'Jul-2007', 'Jun-2007', 'Mar-2017', 'Feb-2017',
           'Jan-2017', 'Dec-2013', 'Nov-2013', 'Oct-2013', 'Sep-2013',
           'Aug-2013', 'Jul-2013', 'Jun-2013', 'May-2013', 'Apr-2013',
           'Mar-2013', 'Feb-2013', 'Jan-2013', 'Dec-2012', 'Nov-2012',
           'Oct-2012', 'Sep-2012', 'Aug-2012', 'Jul-2012', 'Jun-2012',
           'May-2012', 'Apr-2012', 'Mar-2012', 'Feb-2012', 'Jan-2012',
           'Sep-2016', 'Aug-2016', 'Jul-2016', 'Dec-2017', 'Nov-2017',
           'Oct-2017', 'Dec-2016', 'Nov-2016', 'Oct-2016', 'Mar-2019', 'Feb-2019',
           'Jan-2019', 'Jun-2019', 'May-2019', 'Apr-2019', 'Sep-2019', 'Aug-2019',
           'Jul-2019']
df=pd.Series(lst)
df=pd.to_datetime(df)
```

Your last date entries are having invalid year.

Comment: I have given example in lst, i have so many invalid entries, how can i change them

Comment: that's why we use pandas, so we can read a large amount of data and before proceeding further you first have to correct your data such as handling missing values, inappropriate data, doing data imputations, etc, and then later you can perform your business logics